# Is .CSV file broken down and processed in parallel by Spark

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a .csv file that is 100GB in size.
I want to load it in Spark as fast as possible.

Internally does Spark break down the file into chunks and parses the chunks in parallel on multiple nodes?
Or does Spark parse the file only using one node and distributes the dataframes in between the nodes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default Spark will divide the **`CSV file`** into **`~128MB`** chunks for each thread and reads the **`CSV`** file in distributed manner.

**`Example:`**

Reading csv file `3126179159` bytes in yarn cluster mode, divided into `24` partitions(tasks) and reads the file with parallel threads that are available for your application!

```
i.e 3126179159/(24*1024) = ~128MB
```

[image]

You can check **`how many partitions`** your file has been divided in spark job UI (or) spark history server UI.  This is equal to the number of completed tasks for the file read. You can find this by looking for 'completed jobs' in the 'jobs' tab of the UI and looking for the file read.

Answer (score 1):

> Internally does Spark break down the file into chunks and parses the
>   chunks in parallel on multiple nodes? Or does Spark parse the file
>   only using one node and distributes the dataframes in between the
>   nodes?

Spark break down the file into chunks called partitions (unit of parllelism) if you are using repartition or if you are not repartitioning default number of partitions it will take.

you can increase or decrease the number of partitions using `repartition`, but can only decrease the number of partitions  using `coalesce`

see [here](https://medium.com/@mrpowers/managing-spark-partitions-with-coalesce-and-repartition-4050c57ad5c4)

Finally based on number of executors and cores it will process the data on multiple nodes or single node based on your spark-submit parameters.